# switch case statement in c does not give result

Tags: c, switch-statement, selection

edit: the name of the game is game of craps, not crap.
Thanks to everyone who tried to help, i forgot to put ctrl= 1 assignment into the for loop.

i cannot get the wanted result from this game of crap. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int rolldice();

int main() {
srand(time(NULL));
int n;
float winrate;
float lossrate;
long int i;
long int ctrw,ctrloss;
ctrw= 0;
ctrloss= 0;
int ctrl= 1;
for(i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    while(ctrl!=0) {
        n= rolldice();
        switch(n) {
            case 7:
            case 11:
            ctrw++;
            ctrl= 0;
            break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 12:
            ctrloss++;
            ctrl= 0;
            break;
            default:
            ctrl= 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
winrate= (float)ctrw/i * 100.0;
lossrate= (float)ctrloss/i * 100.0;
printf("Win rate is %.2f, loss rate is %.2f.",winrate,lossrate);
system("pause");
return 0;
}

int rolldice() {
    int a= (rand()%6)+1;
    int b= (rand()%6)+1;
    return a+b;
}
```

As seen, i am trying to calculate win and loss rate of this game by playing it 100000 times. But what is printed is this: Win rate is 0.00, loss rate is 0.00.
Probably a simple mistake, but i couldn't find and don't want to lose more time for it.

Comment: Start with a shorter loop, and then step through the code line by line in a debugger to see what happens and what it does. And please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: i believe the game is called craps. crap is a totally different game

Comment: You should reset `ctrl` to `1` within the for loop

Comment: Put `ctrl= 1;` inside the for loop. The way you have it, once it gets assigned `0` it never changes.

Comment: Just want to be clear on the game above.  You are getting the percentage of win/loss on the come out roll?  All other aspects of the game are disregarded?

Comment: ...and I assume you know that you're only counting wins and losses on the come-out roll here, and ignoring all games with a point.

Comment: If you get 4,5,6,8,9 or 10, you will have one extra chance to try, this will go on until you get 7,11-win or 2,3,12-loss. So, i counted these extras as one game because they will eventually be a win or a loss.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change this

```
for(i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    while(ctrl!=0) {
```

into

```
for(i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    ctrl = 1;             // Restart the game
    while(ctrl!=0) {
```

In this way you restart the game. If you don't the game is over after the first succesful completion of the game.